# material menu alignment get displayed horizontally when first open and vertically ( as expected ) when refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, build, material-ui

I created react app with a node server and build it with npm run build.
when I first run the app , the material menuItems  get displayed horizontally. It's only when I refresh the page that the menuItems appear verticaly as expected .
any idea aboiut what could be the origin of this issue.
The issue doesn't appear in development . it's after building it that it appear.
[issue_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR55H.jpg)

Comment: On refresh it fixes itself? Are you using localStorage to set items on first load and on reload it applies them? Could be a few things, you can examine the HTML to see if it looks incorrect maybe something wasn't inserted and it broke CSS/HTML of your design. :)

Comment: Are you styling MUI with a style sheet? It could be that the sheet is loading in after the component. If you are using a style sheet, rather move over to a theme provider or style the elements via makeStyles

Comment: I'am using localstorage to store user credentials, Actually I have a login page and a home page .when I firt open the app , the login page appears first and the user get authenticated to be redirected to the home page . so then I must reload the page to get the right alignment. But if when I first open the app and the user is already athenticated ( valid session stored in localstorage ) the user get automatically redirected to the home page without having the alignment issue.  Currently I'am using  window.location.reload() to bypass the issue